# On QCoreApplication and QProcess

Tags: c++, linux, qt

I'm on the path to write a QCoreApplication supposed to create an external process via Qprocess.

I've just noticed that even if the `waitForStarted()` is called and the process state is `Running` before the event handler is executing, the external process *does not start* until the `exec()` method is invoked on the QCoreApplication.

That said, is it possible to postpone the execution of a routine  to the event handling start (in which to instantiate a QProcess), or the only viable way is to create a one shot QTimer?

Comment: I hope it's more understandable now :-)

Comment: It might be more clear if you state that  you want the external process to be confirmed before the event loop starts for the main process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a short investigation it comes out the method **QCoreApplication::processEvents()** that processes all pending events for the calling thread. In the following code

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);

    QProcess abc(....);
    abc.start(...);

    app.processEvents();

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // is the process really running ? //
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    return  app.exec();
}
```

such method is required for the section **`is-the-process-really-running`** to let it find the *abc* process up and running. Otherwise *abc* will be started when the event loop processes the start event.